# Direct maximum likelihood missing outcome

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, optimization, missing-data

In many papers in the social sciences, missing data are handled by *direct* or *full information* maximum likelihood estimation (FIML). Unfortunately this is almost always done with closed source software.

To get an idea how FIML works, I tried to implement it myself in R.

In case of a multivariate normal distribution the loglikelihood for a single observation is given by (according to Enders, 2001, p. 134):

$$
log L_{i} = K_{i} - \frac{1}{2}log|\Sigma_i|-\frac{1}{2}(x_{i}-\mu_{i})^{'}\Sigma^{-1}(x_{i}-\mu_{i})
$$

Where $K_{i}$ is the numer of observed variables for obesrvation $i$.

In case of a simple linear regression model with $N$ observations and assumed homoskedascity the formula should reduce to:

$$
log L_{i} = K_{i} - \frac{1}{2}log(\sigma^{2})-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y_{i}-X_{i}\beta_{i})^{2}
$$

```
set.seed(42)
x <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow=500) ; x <- cbind(1,x)
y <- x %*% c(2,1,3) + rnorm(500, mean = 0, sd = 1)
z.full <- cbind(y,x)

# MCAR predictors
x[sample.int(n = 500, size = 50),2] <- NA
x[sample.int(n = 500, size = 50),3] <- NA
z.miss <- cbind(y,x)

llog.single <- function(z, beta, sigma){
    y <- z[1]
    x <- z[-1]
    idx <- !is.na(x)  # = K_{i}
    return(sum(idx) + dnorm(y, mean = x[idx]%*%beta[idx], sd = sqrt(sigma), log = TRUE))
}

loglikelihood <- function(y, x, theta) {
    p <- ncol(x)
    beta  <- theta[1:p]
    sigma <- theta[p+1]
    return(-sum(apply(cbind(y,x), 1, llog.single, beta = beta, sigma = sigma)))
}

# Full information maximum likelihood 
optim(par = c(0,0,0,1), fn = loglikelihood, method = "BFGS", x=z.mis[,-1], y=z.miss[,1])$par
# OLS on full dataset
lm(V1 ~ V3 + V4, data = as.data.frame(z.full))
```

**My Question**

*What should I do, if there is missing data in the outcome $Y_{i}$?*

From my current point of view I would just ignore cases with missing data in $Y$. Is this correct or is there maybe a better way?

---

Enders, C. K. (2001). A primer on maximum likelihood algorithms available for use with missing data. Structural Equation Modeling, 8(1), 128-141.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify full-information maximum likelihood using the 'lavaan' package.

```
library(lavaan)
mod <- '
V1 ~ V3 + V4
'
fit <- sem(mod, data=as.data.frame(z.full), missing='fiml')
summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks! Actually I was interested in a more technical answer, for example how to specify the log likelihood. I am aware that there are several software packages that can handle missing values with fiml comfortably (open mx, mplus, lavaan).